# What values need to be least selected to optimize indexes with database engine tuning advisor

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing, profiler, database-tuning

For MSSQL 2008 R2 database what values need to be selected minimum to find required indexes when profiler trace given to the database engine tuning advisor ?

These are the values that can be selected at profiler

http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/5274/minimumy.png

I need to select lowest possible variable to record because profiler will run on product environment. I want database engine tuning advisor to find necessary indexes from this profiler recorded trace. So minimum which checkboxes need to be checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to feed your trace data into the Database Tuning Advisor, your best bet is to select the "Tuning" template in the trace properties dialog. This will set all of those selections for you and provide a trace that the DTA can use.

[image]